# Thinkpad x220 not waking from suspend after upgrading to xUbuntu 14.04 from 13.10

Tags: upgrade, xubuntu, 14.04, suspend, thinkpad

I upgraded my xUbuntu 13.10 install to 14.04 yesterday, everything seems to be working fine or eve better than before except suspend.

When I shut the laptop lid xUbuntu suspends as it should. Then when I open the lid gain I am prompted for my password, after I enter it the screen just goes blank again with the suspend light blinking.

Does anybody have any suggestions as to what could be causing this.

Cheers
Jim

Comment: Also if it's any help changing the power settings in the XFCE settings manager doesn't seem to affect anything. If I set the laptop to do nothing when the lid is closed it still goes into sleep mode.

Also, when it resumes to the login screen the screen brightness is set to minimum.

Answer (score 0):

There is an log file, perhaps there are some details:

> /var/log/pm-suspend.log

Perhaps this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1243647

Comment: It does sound very similar, I have attempted updating to the latest stable kernel (3.14.1) in hope that the issue is fixed, but unfortunately no luck there

Also the log file doesn't contain anything that makes much sense to me as to why it's doing this, I have created a copy of it here - http://paste.ubuntu.com/7358536/